# OAuth requirement for publishable add-ons that only act as clients to Google

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-apps-script-addon

Let's say we're developing an editor add-on (meant for publication) that does *not* need to interface to third party services (only to a self-developed API server, `A`). Does `A` need to implement OAuth i.e. issue tokens and so on, or is it sufficient to use the OpenID token received from Google with `ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()` as authentication for `A` (as mentioned at the bottom of [1]) ?

When the users start the plugin, they will anyway be faced with an OAuth consent screen, which mentions the scopes given in the addon's `appsscript.json` manifest file.

I don't find the requirements listed in the developer guide [1] clear when they mention "non-Google services".

In other words, will the Google security review fail my add-on if my API server `A` does not implement OAuth?

Thank you for any clarifications.

Edit : I'm not concerned with sensitive scopes.

[1] https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services

Comment: The API that you are making the request to will determine whether OAuth is needed or not when an HTTP Request is made to the API's url with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`.  The Google add-on only detects whether the Apps Script code is making an HTTP Request with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`.  The add-on review doesn't evaluate the requirements of the API.  If your add-on needs full access to Google Drive and/or GMail, AND you are making an external request, then you'd need a security assessment which costs a lot of money.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gmail add-on connecting to non-Google Services without oAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52000806/gmail-add-on-connecting-to-non-google-services-without-oauth)